# Eclipse UI: Section heading in a TableWrapLayout

Tags: java, layout, swt, eclipse-rcp, jface

I have two sections in an editor that are arranged side-by-side by using the `TableWrapLayout`. As you can see on the screenshot below, the heading of the right section does not use the full width. When expanded, both the heading and the content of the section use the full width. It stays that way when the section is closed again. So the problem only appears when the editor is opened.

So, how do I get the section section to use the full width? 
I already set the `grabHorizontal` attribute of the TableWrapData to `true` and used `GridData.FILL_HORIZONTAL` on the underlying composites.

Of course, setting the section to expanded right away would solve the problem, but I'd like to keep it closed initially because loading the content for that section does some heavy backend stuff and therefore would result in longer loading times for the editor.

[image: Editor]

The code of the editor:

```
public void createPartControl(Composite parent) {
    toolkit = new FormToolkit(parent.getDisplay());

    form = toolkit.createScrolledForm(parent);
    form.setLayoutData(new GridData(GridData.FILL_BOTH));

    toolkit.decorateFormHeading(form.getForm());

    TableWrapLayout layout = new TableWrapLayout();
    layout.numColumns = 2;
    form.getBody().setLayout(layout);

    createMetaInfoSection();
    createUpdateDocumentSection();  
}

private void createMetaInfoSection() {
    Section metaInfoSection = toolkit.createSection(form.getBody(), Section.DESCRIPTION | Section.TITLE_BAR | Section.TWISTIE | Section.EXPANDED);
    TableWrapData twd = new TableWrapData();
    twd.grabHorizontal = true;
    twd.colspan = 1;
    metaInfoSection.setLayoutData(twd);

    // Composite
    Composite composite = toolkit.createComposite(metaInfoSection);
    GridLayout gridLayout = new GridLayout();
    composite.setLayout(gridLayout);
    composite.setLayoutData(new GridData(GridData.FILL_BOTH));

    // Content
    ...

    metaInfoSection.setClient(composite);
}

private void createUpdateDocumentSection() {
    Section updateDocumentSection = toolkit.createSection(form.getBody(), Section.DESCRIPTION | Section.TITLE_BAR | Section.TWISTIE | Section.EXPANDED);
    TableWrapData twd = new TableWrapData();
    twd.grabHorizontal = true;
    twd.colspan = 1;
    updateDocumentSection.setLayoutData(twd);

    // Composite
    Composite composite = toolkit.createComposite(updateDocumentSection);
    GridLayout gridLayout = new GridLayout();
    composite.setLayout(gridLayout);
    composite.setLayoutData(new GridData(GridData.FILL_BOTH));

    // Content
    ...

    updateDocumentSection.setClient(composite);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
TableWrapData twd = new TableWrapData(TableWrapData.FILL_GRAB);
```